# how to get back in Ubuntu after after pressing d in upgrade and

Tags: package-management, uninstall

Just completed upgrade and press D for details. Try returning back removing 64 packages. I was able to get back to #

Please how can I get back and remove the 64 packages.

Thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqxrY.png)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You have not said what version of Ubuntu you are using. What did you upgrade what to what? Are you expecting to be able to undo an upgrade? You need a LOT more info to make this a question.

Answer (score 1):

Your description indicates that you aborted the release upgrade. Happily, you did so at a place that's usually easy to recover from.

- In the future, use 'Q' [Quit] to exit the information screen and return to the release-upgrade.

You cannot resume the release-upgrade, but you can complete the final steps that the script would have done:

```
sudo apt autoremove         // This will remove those obsolete packages
sudo apt autoclean          // This will trim your package cache
sudo snap refresh           // This will update any snaps that need it
```

- Since you are running as root, omit sudo.